# How to solve "PathExistsException" Problem while creating a Flutter Application in VSCODE?

Tags: flutter, dart

While building my flutter application in VS code, I could successfully run the app, everything works fine. But after 2 or more times of restart of the application, whenever I run my code again, the build gets failed. This is the error pops up.

"Target debug_android_application failed: PathExistsException: Cannot copy file (*to a path*). (OS Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
, errno = 183)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."

I copied all the files from the current directory into a newly created directory, and then it works again fine. But even now after running 2 or 3 times again the error pops up. Is there any fix available to this problem?

Comment: Can you produce a MRE code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.